# grep specific matches

Tags: unix, grep

I have these in 1.txt:

```
Modified Reference MM-EE-145 by:
Reference MM-EE-145
Reference S1-123-BCD :
Reference S43-FF-F3-SMY_3 :
Reference PB-xx-xx
```

So, I need to grep the matches starting with Reference -whateverhere- and ending with ':'

```
 grep '^Reference' 1.txt
```

But in the matches I also get lines without the ':' and I don't need those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.*:$` in order to match lines ending with `:`, like this:

```
$ grep "^Reference.*:$" file
Reference S1-123-BCD :
Reference S43-FF-F3-SMY_3 :
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
grep "^Reference.*:$" 1.txt
```

the `:$` bit is where you tell grep that you only want the lines that end with a colon.